# Why does clicking "Browse the complete list of questions" show me only "Featured Questions"?

Tags: bug, questions, question-lists, featured-tag

At the bottom of the "[Top Questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/)" page, is

> Looking for more? Browse the [complete list of questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions), or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions.`

Clicking "[complete list of questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions)" takes me to a page which shows only the [featured questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured).

Is this because the majority of questions have answers already?  This seems incorrect behavior if some questions don't have answers selected.  To be honest, from the text "complete list of questions", I'd expect to see a complete list of every question regardless of state.

I suspect either there is a bug here or something should be re-worded.

Answer (score 3):

The why is easy: it's just taking you to the /questions page, and the main problem is that that page, by default, remembers your preferences.

It should probably be changed to point to [the same page, with the sort set to newest](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), except that going to that page then changes the default sort in the future, which it probably shouldn't. So there doesn't seem to be an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

The questions page (/questions) remembers which tab (newest, featured, frequent, votes, etc.) you selected previously when you return to the page. Some of these are for sorting and some for filtering. Newest is the default tab, and will show all questions.

Try the following:

- Click a different tab (e.g. newest)
- Go to the landing page
- Click the complete list of questions link
- Observe that the questions list's content has changed (should be all questions if you last clicked newest)

The featured questions link you've provided even contains a parameter specifying the "featured" tab (sort=featured), though this might be intentional on your part, for the sake of explanation. I haven't bothered testing to see if a parameter is included on the page.

For anonymous users, they see a button that says "browse more questions":
[image]

Logged in users see something else:

[image]

I suppose that the team expects users with accounts to know how /questions works, and the tab remembering behaves the same whether you're logged in or not (I have not tested whether it persists across log in/out). Technically, you are taken to the complete list of questions, you've simply chosen to filter it. But I agree that this behavior can be confusing. I didn't understand what was going on the first few times it happened to me.

Comment: The parameter was intentional.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that we go to the last question list visited. Unfortunately, while the text works great for first-time visitors who just happen to go to the bottom of the page on their first visit, if a first-time visitor doesn't even make it down the page that far, navigating to a different question list via a tab, then the text used for the link is inaccurate.  Given the case, IMHO it should be re-worded.

Comment: For what it's worth, that isn't the text that new (anonymous) users see. I'll edit.

Comment: If it isn't, then it is even more inaccurate, IMHO.

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking "complete list of questions" takes you to the `/questions` page on the respective site, which the default behavior is set to open the tab you were last browsing.  If you were to click the "Unanswered" tab and then click "complete list of questions" again, it would take you to the unanswered tab this time